# Invisible value when creating new record

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have problem with some form in Access 2010. In one of the fields (Amount) I have as a value expression =IIf([IsNull([Code]);1;2) . In the form the values 1 and 2 are shown correctly but when I try to save the newly created record I have an error: You have to fill the Amount field. Can someone tell me why the value is not visible when saving new record to database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VBA code on the NewRecord and/or BeforeUpdate event to insert these values into this field/textbox. What you are doing here amounts to setting a value for Display only.